# Why is my list not saving correctly (python)

Tags: python, list

When I print each item separately (see comment below), they come out correctly. However, when I try to populate the list with the dictionaries, it comes out empty! Can anyone figure out why?

```
def getAnnualSnow(allData):
    annualSnow =  []
    year = allData[0]['year']
    totalSnow = 0
    for monthData in allData:
        if year <= 2012:
            if monthData['year'] == year:
                totalSnow = totalSnow + monthData['snow']
            else:
                totalAnnSnow = {'year':year, 'totalsnow':round(totalSnow,1)}
                #print(totalAnnSnow)
                annualSnow.append(totalAnnSnow)
                year = year + 1
                totalSnow = 0
        else:
            return annualSnow
```

Comment: because may be your else part is not executed

Comment: Could you briefly explain what is the data in allData ? It's hard to understand it just from the code.

Comment: rather your else part is *being* executed - is the data same for both invocations?

Answer (score 0):

maybe don't return if list is empty ?
I only changed the last else.

```
    if year <= 2012:
        if monthData['year'] == year:
            totalSnow = totalSnow + monthData['snow']
        else:
            totalAnnSnow = {'year':year, 'totalsnow':round(totalSnow,1)}
            #print(totalAnnSnow)
            annualSnow.append(totalAnnSnow)
            year = year + 1
            totalSnow = 0
    if year > 2012 and annualSnow:
        return annualSnow
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I think what's causing your confusion is that the function doesn't return anything (None?). Look at the modified else part below, I've only added a return statement.

```
def getAnnualSnow(allData):
    annualSnow =  []
    year = allData[0]['year']
    totalSnow = 0
    for monthData in allData:
        if year <= 2012:
            if monthData['year'] == year:
                totalSnow = totalSnow + monthData['snow']
            else:
                totalAnnSnow = {'year':year, 'totalsnow':round(totalSnow,1)}
                #print(totalAnnSnow)
                annualSnow.append(totalAnnSnow)
                year = year + 1
                totalSnow = 0
        else:
            return annualSnow

     # return annualSnow here!! 
     return annualSnow
```

The thing is depending on what you want to do, you could go branching everywhere. You're short-circuiting by returning annualSnow when `year >2012`, but otherwise you're not returning any values from this function. And because you are not printing anything either, you don't see anything.

Try doing:

```
x = getAnnualSnow(allData)
print x
type(x)
```

Given your snippet, it seems like your output should be `None` (but I don't have your data to prove that).

**EDIT**

Having looked at the snippet more closely, this seems like a problem

```
 year = allData[0]['year']
```

What you probably want to do is

```
 year = monthData['year']
```

just before doing `if year <= 2012` comparison. Because as it stands, you're always comparing with the first entry's year to 2012, so whether or not your snippet returns a value is dependent on that fact. It will never get into the 'main' `else` part, if it ever went into the 'main' `if`. (sounds convoluted, as I read again. I hope it is clear)